# scanf is not storing the full set of each line but is stopping at each period and then starting storing from a new line

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

i am tring to read in a series of network addresses similar to

```
 168.12.110.25
 64.113.134.35
 217.158.91.183
 102.130.129.146
 215.116.26.223
 81.162.78.0
 19.204.25.222
  245.124.138.157
  137.249.183.201
  106.61.236.67
  106.71.236.60
  106.81.240.63
 168.14.111.27
  168.17.111.27
  215.116.26.220
  137.249.111.202
  137.246.111.202
```

and store them into netoworks, that has to be a two dimensional array.

```
   //declare libraries
  
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
  
   //declare other functions/files to be used in the program
   void print_fun(void);
   int sort_fun(void);
  void read_fun(void);
 
 
 
  //read command line input and store the information
  int main(int argc, char** argv){
      unsigned char networks[argc][4];
 
      int arg = 0;
      //convert command line argument to int
         arg = atoi(argv[1]);
 
 
      for (int j =0; j<1; ++j){
          if(argc == 1)
               {
                  printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up\n");
              }
 
          else
          {
          // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 unsig char
 
             for(int k = 0; k<arg; ++k){
                  for (int i =0; i<4; ++i){
 
                  scanf("%hhu",&networks[k][i]);
                  printf("%hhu",networks[k][i]);
              }
              printf("\n");
              }}}
 
 
  //sort array
      42 //count networks
 
  //print info about the array
 
  }
```

i am wondering what i am doing wrong. i need to store the information coming in from the file into networks, the scanf is not storing the complete information of each address.

the new output

```
    [p18d541@csci112 program1]$ ./main 17 < inp17.txt
1680640
0000
11000
0000
2481141048
25512700
194000
2000
2311131048
25512700
2919640
17000
1601131048
25512700
1000
0000
20818640
```

how do i change my code to store the network properly.

**EDIT**

with a quick update to the code of adding a period on the scan and print.

```
 //declare libraries
 
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
 
  //declare other functions/files to be used in the program
  void print_fun(void);
  int sort_fun(void);
  void read_fun(void);
 
 
 
  //read command line input and store the information
  int main(int argc, char** argv){
      unsigned char networks[argc][4];
 
      int arg = 0;
     //convert command line argument to int
          arg = atoi(argv[1]);
 
 
      for (int j =0; j<1; ++j){
          if(argc == 1)
               {
                  printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up\n");
              }
 
          else
          {
          // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 unsigned char
 
              for(int k = 0; k<arg; k++){
                  for (int i =0; i<4; i++){
 
                  scanf("%hhu.", &networks[k][i]);
                  printf("%hhu.\",networks[k][i]);
             }
              printf("\n");
              }}}
 
 
  //sort array
 
  //count networks
 
  //print info about the array
 
  }
```

and the new output is,

```
[p18d541@csci112 program1]$ ./main 17 < inp17.txt
1681211025
6411313435
21715891183
102130129146
21511626223
81162780
1920425222
245124138157
137249183201
1066123667
1067123660
1068124063
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

or it has thousands of output.

it is random

Comment: i dont know what your talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` is having a hard time parsing the periods between the numbers, and it's causing it to behave in unexpected ways. Try this instead:

```c
scanf("%hhu.",&networks[k][i]);
printf("%hhu",networks[k][i]);
```

You've also got an issue in your declaration of array size:

```c
unsigned char networks[argc][4];
```

`argc` is how many arguments were passed into the function, not the actual value you passed. This means your array is going to be the wrong size, likely resulting in a segfault. Try this instead:

```c
int arg = 0;
//convert command line argument to int
arg = atoi(argv[1]);

//declared AFTER we have the value we want
unsigned char networks[arg][4];
```

Comment: so that did end up storing the values but then it says segmentation fault (core dumped),

Comment: No way to know why that might be happening; the rest of your code is hidden. You may have bad input data, or errors somewhere further along down the line, or a badly-sized `networks` array, or any number of other issues.

Comment: There is no other part of my code? this is it.

Comment: I may have found the issue - answer has been updated.